# About Murphy's notation: why is $p(y|x, \theta)$ a conditional expectation when there is no probabilistic interpretation on $x$ or $\theta$?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, conditional-probability

In section 1.4.5 of Kevin Murphy ML textbook, he introduces linear regression where for a given data $x$, the target $y$ is assumed to be obtained through

$$y(x) = w^Tx + \epsilon, \text{ where } \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

Since $\epsilon$ is a random variable, therefore $y$ is a random variable as well induced solely by $\epsilon$.

However, the author then defines $$p(y|x, \theta) = \mathcal{N}(y|\mu(x), \sigma^2(x))$$

where $\theta = (w, \sigma^2)$

First of all, $x$ here is explicitly just a vector with no assumption that is was generated according to a distribution. Secondly, $\theta$ here is just the parameters associated with the Gaussian as well as the model, there is no probablistic interpretation as well.

**How does the author condition on two deterministic variables?**

Relevant text below:

---

[image]

Comment: The author doesn't condition: this is merely an abuse of notation.  The two other variables are *parameters.*

Comment: @whuber But this doesn't make sense if you consider the parallel development for logistic regression. It is always $P(y|x)$ conditioned on $x$, https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/pdfs/40%20LogisticRegression.pdf

Comment: It is not.  In logistic regression there is no need to assume $x$ is a random variable.  One proof of that is that there is no probability (or density) associated with $x$ in the expression for the likelihood given in the "Derivations" section.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is not stochastic, then $y$ is just an affine  transformation of the multivariate normal variable $\epsilon$.

When $x$ is stochastic, no distributional assumption is needed. All that is required is that the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ is normal and the marginal distribution of $x$ is unrestricted (see Hansen, [Econometrics](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf), p. 141).

As to $\theta$, in a frequentist setting parameters are just unknown numbers, and one would rather write $p(y;x,\theta)$, but in a bayesian setting parameters are random variables. And Murphy is going to introduce *Bayesian concept learning*...

Comment: The first characterization is deceiving, because *which* transformation $y$ is depends on $x.$ And it's an affine transformation: the linear part merely is $\epsilon$ itself.

Comment: @whuber Yes, "affine" is more technical. I was just saying that if $x$ is non stochastic, then $y=w^Tx+\epsilon$ is like the familiar "linear" (more technically: affine) transformation $Y=a+bX$.

Comment: The concern isn't linear vs affine; it's that even if we use affine, it's not the case that "$y$ is just a [linear or affine] transformation of a normal variable."

Comment: Please, could you explain this point?

Comment: Permit me to illustrate it.  Let $x = (0,10)$ and for each $x$ let $y$ have a Normal distribution with mean $x$ and unit variance.  The resulting $y$ obviously is not Normal: it has a bimodal distribution.  Since all linear (and affine) transformations of Normal variables are also Normal, this $y$ cannot be such a transformation.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I can't get it. If $x=(0,10)$, then $w$ may be $(1,2)$ and $w^Tx=20$. For each $y_i$, $y_i-\epsilon_i$ is a scalar (product). See (1.4) in the text quoted by the OP. What am I missing?

Comment: $(1.4)$ is a *mixture* distribution, not a linear transformation of Normals.  If you're unclear about this, one convincing demonstration is to simulate $(x,y)$ data from the illustrated model and plot a histogram of $y.$

Comment: Isn't it a _multivariate_ distribution, where each $y_i$ is an affine transformation of a normal error? When $x$ is non stochastic, of course.

Comment: Yes -- I think we touched on that point earlier.  Maybe simply writing "$y$ is just an affine transformation of the multivariate Normal variable $\epsilon$" might help clear things up, if that agrees with what you originally meant.  But that seems at best tangential to the question, which concerns how $y$ is related to $x,$ not $\epsilon,$ so perhaps I continue to misunderstand you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. As to how $y$ (a random variable) is related to $x$ (when a non stochastic variable) another time :) Thanks!